# SpringBoot cannot listen to port

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot

I'm using MacOS Sierra.And I use Springboot-cli to generate a blank project and add a basic RESTController:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Object index(){
    return "hello world";
}
```

And I run the project.Everything seems great with the output in console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-05-23 23:54:19.470  INFO 3776 --- [           main] com.bonc.smallETL.ETLApp                 : Starting ETLApp on SLs-Mac.local with PID 3776 (/Users/liuxiaoyang/Desktop/sourceCode/smallETL/smalletl-back/target/classes started by liuxiaoyang in /Users/liuxiaoyang/Desktop/sourceCode/smallETL/smalletl-back)
2017-05-23 23:54:19.473  INFO 3776 --- [           main] com.bonc.smallETL.ETLApp                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-23 23:54:19.571  INFO 3776 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2805c96b: startup date [Tue May 23 23:54:19 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-23 23:54:21.126  INFO 3776 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9999 (http)
2017-05-23 23:54:21.142  INFO 3776 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-23 23:54:21.143  INFO 3776 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-05-23 23:54:21.263  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-23 23:54:21.264  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1699 ms
2017-05-23 23:54:21.401  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-23 23:54:21.405  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-23 23:54:21.405  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-23 23:54:21.406  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-23 23:54:21.407  INFO 3776 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
```

However when I open the browser and visit http://localhost:9999 (I changed the port to 9999 by set server.port=9999 in application.properties),it turns out that connection refused(also via curl).So I check the port with command lsof -i:9999 also with nothing.

```
# liuxiaoyang @ SLs-Mac in ~ [0:08:14]
$ lsof -i:9999

# liuxiaoyang @ SLs-Mac in ~ [0:14:59] C:1
$ sudo lsof -i:9999
Password:

# liuxiaoyang @ SLs-Mac in ~ [0:15:02] C:1
```

However everything seems good and the jps command showing that project JVM has started.
[image]
I'm wondering in which reason the program cannot listen to the configured port while everything looks right.

Comment: When the app starts it lists all the ports it is listening on. Is 9999 in that list? Show us the startup output.

Comment: Try to launch with 'server.port=8090'

Comment: I tried.I also thought is the port problem.However when I changed the port.Nothing change.@Reborn

Comment: Yes,9999 is in the list.Sorry,my network just lost so the picture and the console output can not be posted to the question.Now I have edited the question with the outputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing showed"? Is there no error message? Are you sure you've not got a successful but empty HTTP response? Try using cURL.

Comment: Also please copy/paste text from your terminal, rather an using images.

Comment: ok.connection refuesd: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9999: Connection refused. @slim

Comment: If the browser error is "Connection refused", put that in your question, not "Nothing showed", which is untrue.

Comment: changed.thanks @slim

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the network environment may cause the problem.When I go to company and rerun the project, it works.Amazing.I don't know the detail of the spring boot embedded Tomcat. But I guess the problem is related to the network interface binding since there are many network interface in my computer(with some virtual ones).